# android new style context menu / dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I've been trying to figure out how to create a dialog that looks similar to this context menu that is displayed after preforming a long click on an EditText on the newer versions on android.

[image]

I've been researching the android api to find out if this was included or is custom. However, I haven't had any luck. I've also found this same syle menu in other application such as Astrid.

[image]

I've currently implemented a context menu in my application however, I prefer the style of this new dialog. Than you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a UI pattern, called QuickAction.

For some implementations you check here: https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction, http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/ or the GreedDroid project (https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid).

Hope this helps!